# Is it possible to do object iteration without a separate iterator object?

Tags: python, iterator, iteration

I am writing something similar to an array, but with some tweaks. Of course, it should be iterable. But I do not really want to make another object as an iterator, and 'for I in myObject.generator()' seems too clunky for me. Is there any way to make a generator function that would work for 'for I in myObject'?

Comment: Look into the `__iter__` magic method [__iter__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a generator function for the [`__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

```
def __iter__(self):
    for value in self._values:
        yield value
```

This produces a new generator iterator object each time  [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) is called on the object (which is what `for` does *for you* when you use your object in a loop).